# Moment generating function trouble understanding solution

Tags: statistics

Suppose that Y is a single observation from an exponential distribution
with mean θ.

Use the method of moment-generating functions to show that $\frac{2Y}\theta$ is a pivotal quantity and has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $2$ df.

The solution says $m_u(t) = E(e^{tU}) = E(e^{t\frac{2Y}\theta}) = m_y(2t/\theta) = (1-2t)^{-1}$

What I don't understand is why we let U = $2Y/\theta$ and why does $m_y(2t/\theta)$ = $(1-2t)^{-1}$

Comment: Using $U=\frac{2Y}{\theta}$ seems to be just so it is more clear how to take the mgf. Since $Y$ is assumed to be exponentially distributed, we know what $m_y(t)$ looks like.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Oh wow, total brain fart. Appreciate that